# Tratar o retorno de uma linha de um Datatable nulo

Tags: datatable, return

Estou acostumado a desenvolver em VB.net e estou iniciando um projeto novo em C#.net com VS2013. Percebi que em muitas coisas há uma diferença expressiva na sintaxe e me deparei com uma questão. Como eu trato valores nulos de um Datatable, após uma consulta no Banco de dados?

Como eu faria em relação ao exemplo abaixo?

```
If (objclidto.DtAniversario Is Nothing) Then : cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@DataAniversario", SqlDbType.Date)).Value = DBNull.Value
Else : cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@DataAniversario", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = objclidto.DtAniversario
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar `DBNull.Value` em C#, tal qual em VB:

```
if (objclidto.DtAniversario == null)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(
        new SqlParameter("@DataAniversario", SqlDbType.Date)
        ).Value = DBNull.Value;
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(
        new SqlParameter("@DataAniversario", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        ).Value = objclidto.DtAniversario;
}
```